# Cannot append pickle data stream to text file

Tags: python, dictionary, append, pickle

I am new to Python and I am writing a Python 2.7 code to store account information (username and password) to practice using classes and coding.  The idea is to create an account, create a username and password, and store username and password in a dictionary with the account as key, then use the Pickle module to store the object in a text file. Commands also exist to display the stored accounts, and of course retrieve username and passwords based on account keys.

The way its written now I have to unpickle the whole file for every additional dictionary key and item added, and then truncate the original file and re-pickle the whole dictionary.  Is this the best way to do this? I am trying to be efficient with my code and it seems like the way I've written it isn't as smooth as I'd like, although it seems to work reasonably well (will add error handling soon).  Would appreciate any feedback on whether I can directly append pickle data streams to text files and any other comments on conventions or code efficiency

```
import pickle

class Create(object):

  def __init__(self, account, un_and_pass, pass_dump):
    self.account = account
    self.un_and_pass = un_and_pass
    self.pass_dump = pass_dump

  def write(self, account, un_and_pass, pass_dump):
    storage_file = open("Storage.txt", "r")
    pass_dump = pickle.load(storage_file)
    storage_file.close()
    pass_dump[account] = un_and_pass
    storage_file = open("Storage.txt", "w+")
    pickle.dump(pass_dump, storage_file)
    storage_file.close()

class Retrieve(object):

  def __init__(self, account):
    self.account = account

  def display(self, account):
    storage_file = open("Storage.txt", "r")
    pass_dump = pickle.load(storage_file)
    un_and_pass = str(pass_dump[account])
    un_and_pass = un_and_pass.replace('(',' ').replace(')',' ').replace('\'',' ')
    username, password = un_and_pass.split(",")
    print "Username for", account, "is",username, "\nPassword for", account, "is",password
    storage_file.close()
    on = True   
    while on == True:
      action = raw_input("Please select an option (store, retrieve, display accounts, quit): ")

    if "store" in action:

      account = raw_input("what is this account for?: ")        
      un = raw_input("what is the username?: ")
      password = raw_input("what is the password?: ")
      un_and_pass = un, password
      pass_dump = {}
      c = Create(account, un_and_pass, pass_dump)
      c.write(account, un_and_pass, pass_dump)


    elif "retrieve" in action:
      account = raw_input("Enter account: ")
      d = Retrieve(account)
    d.display(account)

    elif "display" in action:
      storage_file = open("Storage.txt", "r")
      pass_dump = pickle.load(storage_file)
      print "Stored accounts are:"
      for item in pass_dump:
        print item

   elif "quit" in action:
    print "Goodbye"
    on = False

   else:
    print "Command not valid"
```

Comment: Need to fix to make sure all code is in code format.

Comment: From what I understand you are trying to store a pickled dictionary in a txt file?The whole concept of pickling is to store data in a no human readable format. When you pickle a dictionary it you have to give the filename as a parameter. Also use `import cpickle as pickle` its a LOT faster

Comment: @letsc Yes I do not need the text file to be readable, only when the program runs is it meant to be retrieved, in which case I unpickle.  Is this not passing a filename as a parameter when I put pickle.dump(pass_dump, storage_file), storage file is the filename correct as I've assigned it to open("Storage.txt", "w")?  Sorry if questions are basic, really trying to be thorough in learning Python